# Passing the object in a unique pointer as a reference to the other objects' constructor

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

I am using a 3rd party library, which returns a newly created object as a raw pointer. I store it in a `unique_ptr` with a custom destructor to properly destroy the object by calling the library's custom destructor. However, this object will be used by the other objects owned by the same parent class. I wonder if it's an acceptable design to pass the third party object as a reference into the other objects. As they have the same parent, the life time of the 3rd party object can be beyond the other objects as long as it's declared before the other objects that will keep it as a reference. Is there any concerns in this idea, or a better approach? Here is an example:

```
class ChildClass
{
public:
    ChildClass (ThirdPartyClass& third) : thridparty (third)
    {
    // do sth...
    }
private:
    ThirdPartyClass& thirdparty;
};

class ParentClass
{
public:
void addChild()
{
    children.emplace_back (*thirdParty);
}

private:
std::unique_ptr<ThirdPartyClass> thirdParty;
std::vector<ChildClass> children;
};
```

Comment: Just dereference the smart pointer to get the object? There's no need to get the raw non-owning pointer.

Comment: And make sure that the object that `thirdParty` points to have a longer life-time than the `ChildClass` you create.

Comment: a class cannot be named `3rdPartyClass`

Comment: `children.emplace_back (ChildClass (*thirdParty.get()));` --> `children.emplace_back(*thirdParty);`. `emplace_back` forwards arguments to the appropriate constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the life time of the 3rd party object can be beyond the other objects as long as it's declared before the other objects that will keep it as a reference

Yes, class member fields are constructed in the order they are declared in the class body, and destroyed in the opposite order.

> For both user-defined or implicitly-defined destructors, after executing the body of the destructor and destroying any automatic objects allocated within the body, the compiler calls the destructors for all non-static non-variant data members of the class, in reverse order of declaration, then it calls the destructors of all direct non-virtual base classes in reverse order of construction (which in turn call the destructors of their members and their base classes, etc), and then, if this object is of most-derived class, it calls the destructors of all virtual bases.

So, your design is valid and in some circumstances (e.g. you always want to pass a valid object, not `nullptr` to `ChildClass`) recommended.

However, make sure that your `std::unique_ptr<3rdPartyClass> thirdParty;` points to the object returned by your 3rd party library ASAP, preferably in `ParentClass` constructor. Otherwise you can't safely call `addChild` because you risk `nullptr` dereference, which is UB.

Also:

- `3rdPartyClass` is not a valid C++ id
- it's just enough to `ChildClass(*thirdParty)`